# Get Document Library document Templates

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Once you defined additional document Templates within a Sharepoint document Library, how can they be retrieved through MS Graph?

Regarding MS documentation Templates are stored within a Folder called "Forms" (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-a-custom-template-for-a-sharepoint-library-8e0177eb-46bd-4346-9998-330c32733c25). But this folder is neither listed through ms graph nor it can be browsed by path with ms graph. So my Question is how to access these document Templates?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) and [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/list?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) has relationship to `contentType`.

[ContentType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/contenttype?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) resource type has property `documentTemplate` which should be what you are looking for.

Maybe the best way to start is to call Graph API and get `contentType` for your site or list.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/contentTypes
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/contentTypes?$select=id,documentSet,documentTemplate
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/contentTypes
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/contentTypes?$select=id,documentSet,documentTemplate
```

Resources:

[Content type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/contenttype?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Thanks! it is one step forwar. But what about my Templates uploaded through the sharepoint online ui? These are also added as "Template" but are not listed as Templates using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/contentTypes?$select=id,documentSet,documentTemplate.

Comment: I guess that you need to update a documentTemplate on existing content type. You can  also create a new content type and define document template